# Make part of NSString blink (flashing).

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have this time string which contain the `[currentFixture valueForKey:@"time"]` and a afterwords.

How can I make the flashing without making the `[currentFixture valueForKey:@"time"]` flashing.

Inside the cell:

```
 cell.time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'",[currentFixture valueForKey:@"time"]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into NSAttributedString. You could make two strings and set the font color for the apostrophe clear on one and black on the other. Then you just set a timer and alternate calls `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` and set the `attributedText` property on your label.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an NSAttributedString with a different color for the "'" character. Set a timer, and change the color of the "'" a few times a second.